# postgresql: for a given table name what is schema name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, data-dictionary

I have a table name student and like 35 schemas in my DB.
how can i get in which schema the table student exists?
(there might be more than one in different schemas).

I've tried through `pg_class` but I don't know how to get schema name from there.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-class.html The `relnamespace` field points to `pg_namespace.oid`, which contains the schemas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could query it from `information_schema.tables`:

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema 
FROM   information_schema.tables 
WHERE  table_name = 'student'
```

Comment: what table_catalog means? will it work on views as well?

Comment: @John `table_catalog` is the name of the database containing the table. If you already know it, you can omit it from the query. And yes, this will work for views as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
select schemaname,relname from pg_stat_user_tables;
```

Example:

```
dvdrental=# select schemaname,relname from pg_stat_user_tables;
```

| schemaname | relname |
| --- | --- |
| public | actor |
| public | category |
| public | payment |
| public | film |
| public | staff |